# Which widgets are used in Rhythmbox there

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, rhythmbox

I'm building a GUI with GTK+. I want to use the same widgets used by Rhythmbox in the left side-bar. But I can't find them in Glade. Are they just buttons ?

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rhythmbox uses a GtkTreeView with CellRenderers for pixbuf and text.

For question about the structure and widgets used by gtk programs I can highly recommend to use the [Gtk Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector). It also allows you to fool around with the properties and css.